# Can someone explain the difference between the two and why one produces a wrong result; Python instance variables

Tags: python, constructor

Maybe a very noob question but the below gives wrong results when vecDict is initialized outside of init. Can someone please explain why..

```
class Vector:
    #vecDict = {} ## vecDict declared here gives wrong results vs in the init method.
    def __init__(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        """
        self.vecDict = {}
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            self.vecDict[i]=nums[i]
 
    def getDict(self):
        return self.vecDict

    # Return the dotProduct of two sparse vectors
    def dotProduct(self, vec):
        print(vec.getDict())
        print(vec.vecDict)
        """
        :type vec: 'SparseVector'
        :rtype: int
        """
        # print(vec.getDict())
        dotProd = 0
        secDict = vec.getDict()
        for k in secDict:
            if k in self.vecDict:
                dotProd += (self.vecDict[k] * secDict[k])

        # print(self.vecDict)
        # print(secDict)

        return dotProd
```

Vector object will be instantiated and called as:

```
v1 = Vector(numsA)
v2 = Vector(numsB)
ans = v1.dotProduct(v2)
```

Ex input:
numsA = [1,0,0,2,3]

numsB = [0,3,0,4,0]

ans = 8

Comment: If you declare vecDict outside the init scope, it becomes a class variable. Class variables are shared amongst the instances which means it instance will point to the same variable. See [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3) for more information.

Comment: Whats the wrong result your getting exactly? can you specify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're declaring your variable outside of the **init** it is a class variable and therefore its value is shared by all instances of that respective class.

If you want it to be individual for every instance you have to place it inside the **init** and assign via the keyword **self** to the respective instance of the class.

https://pynative.com/python-class-variables/